# Unexpected killall behavior

Tags: macos, kill

From my understanding of `killall name` is that it looks up all processes which name is name. So `killall killall` should lookup and kill itself, so I expected no output. So I'm curious:
Why does it look like that:

```
nathan:~ max$ killall killall
No matching processes belonging to you were found
nathan:~ max$
```

I'm on current OS X.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the Linux man page `killall` won't kill itself.

Edit: I see this isn't mentioned on the OSX man page but it probably has the same behavior.  Reason being is that you can use regexps so it's entirely possible you might accidentally try to kill `killall` when specifiying a regex, and that would make `killall` less useful.

Edit 2: I might be wildly wrong about this, but isn't OSX called "Darwin" - and isn't [this](http://src.gnu-darwin.org/src/usr.bin/killall/killall.c.html) the source code to OSX `killall` then?

I'm a bit rusty on my C, but the following:

> ```
>   if (thispid == mypid)
>         continue;
> ```

in what appears to be a loop iterating through all active processes seems to be a specific check to compare the current process it's trying to kill against it's own PID, so it will skip itself.

Guess you could download that source, remove those two lines, and recompile it if you really wanted a `killall` that would kill itself.

Comment: Can you tell me on which man page you found it?

Comment: The [OSX man page](http://www.unix.com/man-page/OSX/1/KILLALL/) doesn't mention this but [the Linux one](http://linux.die.net/man/1/killall) does.  Might have to check the source code but I would bet they'd act the same way.