# Why does 'killall killall' not work?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, terminal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unexpected killall behavior](https://superuser.com/questions/398577/unexpected-killall-behavior)

If running the command `killall killall` from a terminal (I used Konsole of KDE 4), it says it could not find any process.
`killall` runs, looks for a process called `killall` and should find itself and kill, but it doesn't do that. Why?

Comment: `man killall | grep itself`

Comment: I get the (extremely corner-case) brain-teasing side of the exercise but - why would you ever want to do this? :)

Comment: for fun :-) :-)

Comment: @icyrock.com Never say never. I had several `killall` processes get stuck once and tried to kill them with `killall`. But then the other one also got stuck :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perhaps because it's written to ignore itself?

::looks at source code for `killall`::

http://src.gnu-darwin.org/src/usr.bin/killall/killall.c.html

Yup:

```
if (thispid == mypid)
    continue;
```

Comment: So what do you think is the reason that they skip the killall process itelf - apart from "nonsense"?

Comment: @user3001 it skips it because if it killed itself, it wouldn't be able to finish the job you gave it.

Comment: Indeed! Remember, killall supports regexes. A regex match could be over-eager and match killall itself while also matching the intended set of process names. E.g. `killall --regex 'ki.*'` or similar.  Without this regex support, the feature of checking for self doesn't make much sense, since only `killall` can match `killall`. They code should skip around the test if `--regex` has not been specified. (By the way, it occurs to me there is  gaping absence of a `--glob` option. You will rarely need full blown ERE on process names. If I want to kill `gnome-`everything, how about `gnome-*`.

Answer (score 9):

[man killall](http://linux.die.net/man/1/killall)

> A killall process never kills itself (but may kill other killall processes).

Comment: True enough, but you can 2>/dev/null, and the end state is very much the same as if it had worked.

Comment: Oh sure, make it look easy. The man page in OSX leaves that bit out :-D

Comment: @BrianRoach - Your way had more style ;)